# product.info.details already has a child with alias 'additional'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

> [2019-07-04 07:03:12] main.CRITICAL:
> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The element
> 'product.info.details' already has a child with alias 'additional' in
> /var/www/html/elec/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/html/elec/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php(319):
>
> Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->_insertChild('product.info.de...',
> 'product.attribu...', NULL, 'additional')

Comment: did you create any new xml file ?

Comment: or did you overide any xml file ? share that code